# Codeigniter 4 - How to custom the file name for the downloaded file (with different file extension like jpg, jpeg / pdf)?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i just new to learn the codeigniter 4. How can I amended below code to download the file from database with custom file name and the correct extension. Thank you.

```
public function download($payment_id){


    $invoicePaymentModel = new InvoicePaymentModel();
    $file = $invoicePaymentModel ->find($payment_id);

    return $this->response->download('uploads/'.$file['payment_proof'], NULL)->setFileName("testing");


    
}
```

Comment: That should be the working method, what error are you getting? Can you post the error or describe the behavior you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

[Force File Download](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html#force-file-download)

> If you set the third parameter to boolean `true`, then the actual file
> MIME type (based on the filename extension) will be sent, so that if
> your browser has a handler for that type - it can use it.

```php
// ...
return $this->response->download('uploads/'.$file['payment_proof'], NULL, true);
// ...
```

> Use the optional `setFileName()` method to change the filename as it
> is sent to the client’s browser:

```php
// ...
$path = 'uploads/' . $file['payment_proof'];

return $this->response->download($path, NULL)
    ->setFileName("testing" . "." . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// ...
```